# Meta Tag not updating on Google

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, seo, meta-tags

I am working on a rails app which is deployed on heroku. I have placed a meta tag within the head tag in my application.html.erb file but it hasn't changed on Google yet. I have waited over 5 days. Google is still showing text taken from my homepage.

There are also two other meta tags which seem to be auto-generated as seen in the page source excerpt below (i.e. csrf-param and csrf-token). Do these affect the meta description on Google.

Below are excerpts of the relevant files:

**Excerpt of  tag in application.html.erb:**

```
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
<meta name="App Name" content="App description.">
```

**Excerpt of sitemap.xml**

```
<lastmod>2013-08-12T18:29:06+00:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
```

**Excerpt of page source on Google Chrome:**

```
<html>
  <head>
<title>App Name</title>
    <link href="/assets/application-f915aa342a5dbd5b43771fda8cc.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/application-6f2b9741258790f721edcb490ef.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="DCzmx+4h+r3wNv5sMTwS7U5X7u/RizzttU4U9+23DgY=" name="csrf-token" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta name="App Name" content="App description.">
</head>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<meta name="Description" content="App description.">
```

Instead of "App Name"

Google will index the "Description" meta tag:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en